# how to fix "Java source root points to a non-existent location: " error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to get familiar with jetpack compose. I cloned the Android Developer Codelab, and I'm practicing the [Navigation Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-navigation#3).

I haven't even done much in the codelab, but when i run the code I get an error;

[image: Java source root points to a non-existent location, image]

I don't know the cause, or what is needed to solve this.

So I'm going to just paste the gradle files. Not to have a lengthy question. If you need anymore information, I'll happily provide it. Thanks in Advance.

Build.Gradle (Project Module);

```
buildscript {
    // Define versions in a single place
    ext {
        // Sdk and tools
        compileSdkVersion = 32
        minSdkVersion = 21
        targetSdkVersion = 32

        // App dependencies
        appCompatVersion = '1.4.2'
        activityComposeVersion = '1.6.0-alpha03'

        composeVersion = '1.2.0'
        // composeCompilerVersion = "1.2.0"
        composeCompilerVersion = "1.3.0-rc01"
        coreTestingVersion = '2.1.0'
        espressoVersion = '3.4.0'
        gradleVersion = '7.2.1'

        kotlinVersion = '1.7.10'
        // kotlinVersion = '1.7.0'
        ktlintVersion = '0.45.2'
        ktxVersion = '1.8.0'
        materialVersion = '1.6.1'
        navigationComposeVersion = '2.5.0'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradleVersion"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.diffplug.spotless' version '6.7.0'
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.diffplug.spotless'
    spotless {
        kotlin {
            target '**/*.kt'
            targetExclude("$buildDir/**/*.kt")
            targetExclude('bin/**/*.kt')

            ktlint(rootProject.ktlintVersion)
            licenseHeaderFile rootProject.file('spotless/copyright.kt')
        }
    }
}
```

Build.gradle (App module);

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.compose.rally"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        // We use a bundled debug keystore, to allow debug builds from CI to be upgradable
        debug {
            storeFile rootProject.file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion rootProject.composeCompilerVersion
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude "META-INF/licenses/**"
        exclude "META-INF/AL2.0"
        exclude "META-INF/LGPL2.1"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.appCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$rootProject.ktxVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.materialVersion"

    // Compose
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:$rootProject.activityComposeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$rootProject.navigationComposeVersion"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$rootProject.composeVersion"

    // Testing dependencies
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.coreTestingVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$rootProject.espressoVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.espressoVersion"

    // Compose testing dependencies
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$rootProject.composeVersion"
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        // Treat all Kotlin warnings as errors
        allWarningsAsErrors = true

        freeCompilerArgs += '-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn'

        // Set JVM target to 1.8
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help, in Advance. Again, if you need anymore information I'm happy to provide.

Comment: Does the path for your project files include any spaces? I'm running into this same error by just creating a project from one of the templates (Navigation Drawer Activity), zero changes, but the version with a space in the path doesn't compile whereas the version without spaces in the path does.

Comment: @ScottSalyer No it did not have spaces.. I couldn't find a way to fix the error... So I created a new project, and started again.

Comment: @ScottSalyer If you are able to fix, please let me know how you did it.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm new to Android dev so outside of creating the new project, not a clue. Sorry!